# Finding how to populate a field in Powershell with JiraPS

Tags: powershell, jira, jira-rest-api

So, i'm using JiraPS to create some tickets and so far i've been able to work out through trial and error how to populate certain standard and custom fields.

I'm now wanting to create a ticket and link to other tickets. I'm looking to use a standard field called "Linked Issues"

[Linked Issues Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYXni.png)

I've exported all the Jira fields and think this is one of these fields:

ID          : issuelinks
Searchable  : True
Schema      : @{type=array; items=issuelinks; system=issuelinks}
Name        : Linked Issues
Custom      : False
Navigable   : True
Orderable   : True
ClauseNames :

and possibly "subtasks" for the issues field:

ID          : subtasks
Searchable  : False
Schema      : @{type=array; items=issuelinks; system=subtasks}
Name        : Sub-Tasks
Custom      : False
Navigable   : True
Orderable   : False
ClauseNames : subtasks

I only think this as "items" match issuelinks.

I note that these are array records and have tried to no avail to give them a value when creating a ticket.

I get these errors:

Invoke-JiraMethod:  subtasks -------- Field 'subtasks' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.

nvoke-JiraMethod:  issuelinks ---------- Field does not support update 'issuelinks'

If anyone has any ideas if I'm on the right track or way off!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to work it out. I was thinking about it the wrong way, what I've done now is link the ticket to the parent, rather than trying to attach the child. Hope that makes sense...

I've used Add-JiraIssueLink on the child ticket(s) to link to the parent.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).